# Flatten a nested json and get object keys

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

I get json from client side which is nested, I want to faltten it and make the children object keys, preferably using underscore.js.

For example that is my json:

```
var data = {   
    or:[
    {
        dealershipCompany : 11
    },
    {
        authType: 'google'
    }],
    and: [
    {
        or: [
        {
            firstName: {'contains': 'search'}
        },
        {
            lastName: {'contains': 'search'}
        },
        {
            email: {'contains': 'search'}
        }]
    }]
};
```

I want to remove both 'or' & 'and'

and when I get the object keys using Object.keys(data) I get

```
['0','1','2','3','4','5']
```

but I want it to be like this

```
['dealershipCompany', 'authType', 'firstName', 'lastName','email']
```

I tried several times to flatten it by myself but always object keys get numbered

Here the link of [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SuperMedo/w71549z2/)

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried and achieved? Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Did you try to create a new object by taking the objects contained in `or` and `and` and put them in the root of your new object ?

Comment: What are the expected results? Show the code you used to get that final array. This isn't a code writing service, the idea is to help you make code you write do what you want it to. Without a clear goal it is hard for anyone to help

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice,  I'm going to edit my post right now

Comment: @AnthonyGranger I did that, still  the objects get keyed by themselves

Comment: @Rajesh I added jsFiddle so please check it out.

Comment: @charlietfl, You are right, and I do apologize, I actually read my question and I don't know how it came like this, sometimes my brain just down, so I edited my post, in tl;dr I want to turn the elements inside 'or' to be Object keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
var data = {   
    or:[ 
      { dealershipCompany : 11 },
      { authType: 'google' }
    ],
    and: [ {
        or: [
          { firstName: {'contains': 'search'} },
          { lastName: {'contains': 'search'} },
          { email: {'contains': 'search'} }
        ]
    }]
};

function getOnlyObjects(data) {
  var result = [];

  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    data.forEach(function(item) {
      result = result.concat(
        getOnlyObjects(item)
      );  
    });
  }
  else {
    Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
      if (Array.isArray(data[key])) {
        result = result.concat(
          getOnlyObjects(data[key])
        );
      }
      else {
        result = result.concat(data);
      }
    });
  }

  return result;
}

function getData(data) {
  return getOnlyObjects(data).map(function(item) {
    return Object.keys(item)[0];
  });
}

console.log(getData(data));
```

Outputs:

```
["dealershipCompany", "authType", "firstName", "lastName", "email"]
```

Comment: Thanks this work flawlessly, now I'm going to read the code carefully and Bundestag how it works .

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Object.keys` over array, you will get indexes, hence you were getting `['0','1','2','3','4','5']`.

#### Edit 1

Have migrated `=== 'and'`, `=== 'or'` to an array `exceptionList`. You can add further keys that you need to filter. This will keep filtering manageable and condition clean.

---

#### Code

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/w71549z2/1/)

```js
var data = {
  or: [{
    dealershipCompany: 11
  }, {
    authType: 'google'
  }],
  and: [{
    or: [{
      firstName: {
        'contains': 'search'
      }
    }, {
      lastName: {
        'contains': 'search'
      }
    }, {
      email: {
        'contains': 'search'
      }
    }, ]
  }]
};

var result = [];
  
// You can add further keys that you want to filter
var exceptionList = ["and", "or"];

function getKeys(obj) {
  var _keys = Object.keys(obj);
  _keys.forEach(function(key) {
  
    // Check if key is either,`and`, `or`, or an index of array.
    if (exceptionList.indexOf(key) >=0 || !isNaN(key)) {
      getKeys(obj[key]);
    } else {
      result.push(key);
    }
  });
}

getKeys(data);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Your answer is very clear and exceptionListv will future proof the solution specially that json is waterline ORM query, thanks.